# mysql select last type of data with value > 0

Tags: mysql, select

Please guys i need this for huderstand....

I would like to understand how to select a table from the values ​​of a field with id highest but only those if they have another value greater than zero

examples
table

```
id  data         cod     name     tot
3  2013-10-16    AC      acacia   10
2  2013-10-15    AB      abacia    0
1  2013-10-14    AB      abacia   10
```

the selection must give me AC only because the last id of AB is zero .....
I hope I explained ...
thank you very much   :-)

Comment: Not sure if I understand you correctly?  AC does not have another value greater than zero.  Do you mean with values *only* greater than zero?

Comment: I guess it's the "tot" column

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT cod FROM t WHERE tot > 0 ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1
```

Some explanation: to get max id we order by id going from greatest to lowest (DESC) and the "greater than zero" condition is brought into the WHERE clause.

Answer (score -1):

use mysql syntax as following

```
mysql> SELECT * FROM your_table_name WHERE id>0 ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 0,1;
```

if only cod column the

```
mysql> SELECT cod FROM your_table_name id>0 ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 0,1;
```

Comment: These examples ignore the "another value" which I guess is "tot"

Comment: I'm sorry I said bad .. I try to explain better: I want to select for each type of cod only one record, the last if greater than zero if the last is zero should not be visible